# Attributes of multiple associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I want to do something like this:

**@book.chapters.words.uniq**

A book has_many chapters. A chapter has_many words.

How is this accomplished using active record?

Alternatively, how can in be accomplished using raw sql?

Comment: How does this work?  A book has_many chapters?  Then a chapter has_many words?

Comment: show schema or models please.

Comment: It's like @japed said...

Answer (score 5):

You can do this

```
class Book
  has_many :chapters
  has_many :words, -> { uniq }, through: :chapters
end
```

Then `@book.words`

Comment: Oh yeah.. that makes sense. Foggy head today.

Comment: by the way, bonus points for putting the uniq into the association !

Comment: Not really sure how you'd do it without putting it on the association without writing a convoluted method that does that same thing.

Comment: Yeah, for some reason I just wasn't thinking to do it in the assoc... and I was thinking convoluted thoughts about writing a method.. Glad I asked here.